# Downloading from github - there seems to be a directory missing (azure-iot-sdk-c)

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am working thru this Tutorial
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-central?pivots=programming-language-ansi-c)

Was able to perform all steps to install the SDK and samples.
In the next step - when I ran the sample code:

> cmake\iothub_client\samples\pnp\pnp_temperature_controller\Debug\pnp_temperature_controller.exe

Encountered an error that states:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

When I look into my directory system & follow the path of the sample code above I see that the path ends at

> cmake\iothub_client\samples\pnp\pnp_temperature_controller\

This section is missing

> \Debug\pnp_temperature_controller.exe

Missing:
(Directory: "Debug"
File: "pnp_temperature_controller.exe")

Have I done something wrong or is this missing from the repository. I somehow think that I did something wrong but I cannot see where.

Any help on this would be helpful. Thanks
Weng

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to complete the step3 under **Install the SDK and samples** successfully?

```
cmake -Bcmake -Duse_prov_client=ON -Dhsm_type_symm_key=ON -Drun_e2e_tests=OFF
cmake --build cmake
```

Please ensure you have installed cmake and path is updated in your machine.

I had the same issue initially and then checked the cmake version and appears to be not added to the system Path.
[image]

Once cmake is installed and updated the PATH, I tried the example again and able to run it successfully.

[image]

**Output** from the Azure IoT Central page device telemetry graph.

[image]